# Transaction could not be captured by ePay: -1007

Tags: magento

I am doing a automatic subscription through epay payment gateway from magento.

The epay responses the transaction id after payment, but in magento it shows under the status history: "Transaction could not be captured by ePay: -1007"

Please, help me what does it mean? If epay can't do the payment, then it can't response the transaction id. But it shows error?

Thanks in advance
Bratati

Answer (score 1):

-1007   There are differences in the amount captured / available. Please examine the amount of which is captured / credited against the amount authorized / captured. Note if there is a Euroline transaction and the transaction is captured, it can only be credited the following day.

Check epay responses and compare in your code